# format labelText with amCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, amcharts

Iam trying to format the numbers with amCharts.
I would like to format the numbers with a precision of 2 but when I insert:

```
graph.numberFormatter = {precision:2, decimalSeparator:'.', thousandsSeparator:','};
```

it only formats the number from the tooltip and as you can see on the image not all numbers are formatted.

[image: am stacked column chart]

```
graph.labelText = "[[coding]] €";
```

How can I format the labelText?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't reference your 'valueField' directly.  Instead use the inbuilt tag [[value]].  So your example would become

```
graph.labelText = "[[value]] €";
```

In my case I had exactly the same problem when I was using

```
"graphs" : [{
        "labelText" : "[[s1]]",
        "valueField" : "s1",
        ...
    }
],
```

Changing it to

```
"graphs" : [{
        "labelText" : "[[value]]",
        "valueField" : "s1",
        ...
    }
],
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggest:

```
"graphs":[{
     "labelText":"[[value]]",
     "labelFunction": function(graphDataItem, graph){
            var value = graphDataItem.values.value;
            value = formatTextLabel(value);
            return value;
      }
 }]
```

and formatTextLabel is a function such as:

```
function formatTextLabel(value){
    value = value.toString();
    var pattern = /(-?\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (pattern.test(value))
        value = value.replace(pattern, "$1,$2") + "$";
    return value;
}
```